# decimaltobinary (java.lang.NumberFormatException)

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I tried to do a little program that converts decimal to binar.
My Program works quite well for int < 1024. if I type in 1024 or higher I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10000000000"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at ConvertoBinary.binaryform(ConvertoBinary.java:35)
>       at ConvertoBinary.main(ConvertoBinary.java:20)

this is my javacode:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConvertoBinary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number; 

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Geben sie eine positive Dezimalzahl ein:");
        System.out.print("Dezimal: ");
        number=scanner.nextInt();

        if (number <=0)
            System.out.println("Error: Keine positive Dezimalzahl erkannt");
        else { 

            System.out.print("Binär: ");
            System.out.print(binaryform(number));
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static int binaryform(int number) {

       String rest = "";

       while (number > 0) {
           rest = number%2 + rest;
           number = number/2;

       }

      number = Integer.parseInt(rest);
      return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably better suited to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the result with `int` that exceed the limit of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You  should return result `String` instead of `int`

```
public static String binaryform(int number) {

   String rest = "";

   while (number > 0) {
       rest = number%2 + rest;
       number = number/2;

   }

  //number = Integer.parseInt(rest); Commented it
  return rest;
}
```

Comment: ty very much - just that easy :D

Answer (score 0):

`"10000000000"`, this binary form is too large to convert and fit in an int. The max value that an integer can be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is `2147483647`. The `Integer` class however provides an useful function [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) to convert the given integer to binary String.